# how to fetch previous or next record on MongoDB with C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I want to fetch the previous and next record, based on record's insert datetime.

After check out the [official document](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-csharp-driver/), I still had no idea how to do.

Anyone can help me, use C# or Linq?

Comment: You can't really do that without building your own custom solution (like storing the previous/next IDs somewhere).

Comment: I misinterpreted the question, so here is my original answer as a comment... `db["collection"].Find().SetSortOrder(SortBy.Ascending("_id"));` will return all documents sorted by creation date/time. The [MongoDB ObjectId](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/) `_id` contains the creation date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 4 high-order bytes of the `_id` field represent a timestamp, and you can query based on that field. The timestamp is only accurate to one second, so ordering the documents by _id does not guarantee a strict ordering by insertion time. However, it does give you a strict ordering of documents that's approximately ordered by insertion time.

If that's good enough for your case, here's some sample code.

Our sample document that is saved in the collection:

```
class Entity
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
}
```

Assume that we have some MongoCollection `collection`, we can find the previous record for an Entity object  `entity` as follows:

```
IMongoQuery query = Query.LT("_id", entity.Id);
IMongoSortBy sort = SortBy.Descending("_id");
MongoCursor<Entity> cursor = collection.Find(query).SetSortOrder(sort).SetLimit(1);
if (cursor.Size() > 0)
{
    Entity previousEntity = cursor.First();
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Found {0} as the previous entry.", previousEntity.Id));
}
```